# Give an explicit ring isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> I want to give an explicit isomorphism between $\mathbb{F}_7[X]/(X^2+2X+2)$ and  $\mathbb{F}_7[X]/(X^2+X+3)$.

I think the way to do it would be to send a root $\alpha$ of $X^2+2X+2$ to the element $\beta$ of $\mathbb{F}_7[X]/(X^2+X+3)$ so that $\beta$ is a root of $(X^2+X+3)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $X^2+X+3=0$ and be rewritten as $4X^2+4X+12=0$, and then as $(2X+1)^2+4=0$.

Also, $X^2+2X+2=0$ can be rewritten as $(2X+2)^2+4=0$.

Comment: Hello. Thanks. I still do not know how to finish it, could you please do so? I'm sure it's simple but I cannot get it all day.

Comment: The question has a homework feel, so I am reluctant to write full detail. But here goes. By fooling around with the hint, or more directly, $(X+3)^2+2(X+3)+2=X^2+X+3$.